# How to use normal dart functions/custom query in Firebase Firestore database query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
int getDateDifference(var k){
  int i = DateTime.now().difference(k).inSeconds;
  return i;
}

final CollectionReference ordersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('allOrders');
ordersRef
      .where(getDateDifference('created'), isLessThan: 200)
```

From the code above, I want to filter by firebase database to only show data in which the dateTime 'created' field when compared to the current dateTime is less than 200 secs.
And this is a custom query. When write this code, it runs an exception.
How do I write a custom query in firestore database

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `where` is the name of the field on which you want to filter. It needs to be a literal string.

The second argument is the value that you want to filter on. In your case *this* is where you want to perform the calculation, to only return documents where the `created` field has a value of less than a specific value.

So something like:

```
ordersRef
      .where('created', isLessThan: getDateDifference(200))
```

Comment: Ok thank you. But from the function getDateDifference, I need to pass in the value of the ‘created’ field to actually calculate the date difference in seconds

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible. The value you pass needs to be a concrete value, it cannot be a comparison to a different field. It's a bit hard to say what your exact use-case is though, as typically time-to-live scenarios work the way I show here.